# How to Write LAG() Function to Calculate Date Difference in PROC SQL SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to write a code in SQL SAS to calculate difference of days when a user was seen.

As an example of a raw data is following:

```
USER     DATE
User1    20200516
User1    20200513
User1    20200501
User2    20200515
User2    20200511
```

How to write a LAG() Function so the output table should look like following:

```
USER     DATE       PREV_DATE    DIFF
User1    20200516   20200513     3
User1    20200513   20200501     12
User2    20200515   20200511     4
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to do this in PROC SQL? Much easier in a Data Step.

Comment: @draycut it can be done in Data step as well. Thanks

Comment: This is best done in a data step, unless your data is in a database and your are using a remote connection.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am running the code within SAS environment. I will now look into automating the results to a local ftp from SAS everyday.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a data step approach

```
data have;
input USER $ DATE :anydtdte.;
format date yymmddn8.;
datalines;
User1 20200516
User1 20200513
User1 20200501
User2 20200515
User2 20200511
;

data want;
    merge have
          have(firstobs=2 rename=(date=prev_date user=_user));
    if user=_user;
    diff=date-prev_date;
    drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This makes sense. The only part which i am unsure is the data have;
Since i am reading from a table Work.Table_A

Do i write the code:  
data have;  
set WORK.Table_A (obs=100);  
format date yymmddn8.;  
run;

Comment: Confirming with you as the 2 values i have are 20200516 and 20200412. From the code you shared the diff = 104 for that. But in actual the difference of date should be 34.      
And for some reason i am getting dates as *******.

Comment: The data values in the table are NOT date values but meant to look like one. The values are either numeric, encoded to look like a date value (y*10000+m*100+yy), or a string representing a date value.  If character, the log will show `Character values have been converted t
...`    You will need to convert the values in **your** `date` variable into SAS date values before doing date arithmetic.  This expression should work `diff = input(cats(date),yymmdd8.)-input(cats(prev_date),yymmdd8.);`

Comment: Thanks Richard, that makes sense and solved the issue as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't use sas so please take my answer as hint for usage of `lag` function, other issues such as date conversion or computing difference is up to you. This is solution in Postgres (columns renamed to avoid clashes):

```
with t(user_col,date_col) as (values
  ('User1', date '2020-05-16'),
  ('User1', date '2020-05-13'),
  ('User1', date '2020-05-01'),
  ('User2', date '2020-05-15'),
  ('User2', date '2020-05-11')
), lags as (
  select user_col
       , date_col
       , lag(date_col) over (partition by user_col order by date_col) as prev_date
  from t
)
select user_col, date_col, prev_date, date_col - prev_date as diff
from lags
where prev_date is not null
order by user_col asc, date_col desc
```

[Dbfiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a0866ba5457bec6cf3a1495332b33a87)

Please for the next time, provide sample input as CTE (with clause) directly in question.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I don't have an issue with PSQL, as it has a lag function. Thanks for your input though :)

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand your question in a way you are looking for emulation of `lag` function since I didn't know there was not such one in SAS. Then the workaround with self join makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have the concept of LAG baked in and SAS SQL does not implement windowed functions or CTEs

The result set you want can be obtained using a reflexive join and SAS SQL automatic remerge feature.

```
data have;
attrib
  user length=$8
  date length= 8 format=yymmdd10. informat=yymmdd10.
;
input USER DATE;
datalines;
User1    20200516
User1    20200513
User1    20200501
User2    20200515
User2    20200511
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    LEFT.user
  , LEFT.date
  , RIGHT.date as PREV_DATE
  , LEFT.date - RIGHT.date as DIFF
  from
    have as LEFT
  left join
    have as RIGHT
  on
    LEFT.user = RIGHT.user
  where
    LEFT.date > RIGHT.date
  group by
    LEFT.date
  having
    DIFF = MIN(DIFF)
  order by
    LEFT.user, LEFT.date desc, RIGHT.date desc
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for your reply.

Comment: YW and welcome to stackoverflow Khalid.  Help others know what's what, you can learn more about accepting and marking useful answers here -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers